# OG how to contrain a group to a maximum number of users

Tags: organic-groups

I would like to restrict groups to a certain amount of members. Is there any ways to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Organic Groups join limit](http://drupal.org/project/og_limit)
This module allows to set a join limit on a specific group.

Comment: What's the solution for Drupal 7?

Comment: https://drupal.org/node/1347870 - looks like owner of this module doesn't support it yet. Anyway, I assume it can be accessed via Rules module...